# Importing CSV data into Rails app, using something other then the association "id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv

I am trying to import a few CSV files into my rails app. I learned and managed to import tables into Models without association.

Now i have managed to import the data into a table that has associations, but only by entering the actual "id" number on the CSV column. Although functional, this isn't really an option because i have many tables with thousands of IDs.

My main goal is to be able to use the column in the CSV and type in the actual value (that exists in the other model it is associated with), instead of the id number.

I have a Country model and a Ports model. The Ports model is associated with country_id

Port Model

```
class Port < ApplicationRecord
  def self.import(file)
    #code
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      port = find_by_id(row["id"])
      Port.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end

  belongs_to :shipment_type
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :origins, :class_name => 'Rate'
  has_many :destinations, :class_name => 'Rate'
end
```

Country Model

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  def self.import(file)
    #code
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Country.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end

  has_many :ports, dependent: :destroy
end
```

schema.db

```
  create_table "ports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "port_code"
    t.integer  "shipment_type_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "country_id"
    t.index ["country_id"], name: "index_ports_on_country_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["shipment_type_id"], name: "index_ports_on_shipment_type_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "country_code"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "shipment_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The associations are working because i am able to manually add them view my forms i create just fine.

```
<%= form_for(port) do |f| %>
  <% if port.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(port.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this port from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% port.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :port_code %>
    <%= f.text_field :port_code %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :shipment_type_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :shipment_type_id, ShipmentType.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country_code %>
    <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :country_code %>
  </div>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated. I have been going in circles with this for days now.

ADDING SAMPLE TABLE FROM CSV FILE.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not quite following what exacly you are asking? Can you try to be more specific in your question? Is your problem entering the foreign key automatically?

Comment: I think a sample of the data should suffice!

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. Getting a hang of this commenting section.

So I have a large CSV file that contains the following columns :
-name (airport name)
-port_code (airport code ex: JFK, LAX)
- shipment_type (air or ocean) is currently associated to the Shipment_Type table
-country_code (ex: US, DE, CN) currently associated to the Country table.

Comment: Put it in the question so that others can see. I am still not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish ...

Comment: are you using the port where you find it by id? `port = find_by_id(row["id"])`

Comment: But when I try to import the csv file, it doesn’t allow me because Shipment Type “Air” doesn’t “exist” so I have to enter it as a “1” in that column. And for the country_code instead of entering US or CN I have to enter “233” or “154”. 

My goal is to be able to import the CSV with the actual values instead of the ID number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shipment_type is a ruby object, you want to send a string.

If you are needing to import relationships, add methods on the `Port` model like so

```
class Port < ApplicationRecord

  def shipment_type_name
    shipment_type.try(:name)
  end

  def shipment_type_name=(name)
    self.shipment_type = ShipmentType.where(:name => name).first_or_create
  end

  def country_country_code
    country.try(:country_code)
  end

  def country_country_code=(code)
    self.country = Country.where(:country_code => code).first
  end


end
```

Then in the CSV you'd send a `shipment_type_name` and `country_country_code` attributes.

You would do something similar to other relationships.

Comment: This is starting to make more sense. Would this code be added to my Port controller or Port Model?

Comment: To the Port model.  Yes, you can trigger methods by sending them as attributes in a form.  The method can be more complicated as well, handling case issues, etc.  You will also need to make sure they attributes are allowed in the mass assignment.

Comment: It Worked! Now if i am going to include the country_id, and other attributes later, does the ".first_or_create" go with all of them or just one them. Not sure if it overlaps or anything like that.

Thanks again, this was awesome.

Comment: So now there's a little problem. It's actually adding a NEW port_code US to the Country database every time i add a port. Which leads me to believe it's not actually "pulling" from the Country table when i import. What route to go to fix this issue?

Comment: port_code is on the port table, do you mean country_code?  btw, code is a great column to `first_or_create` by, is that what you are using?  And, what do you mean you will add country_id later?

Comment: Added details about country code.  Also, I'd add validations to country if you need `country_code` to be unique.

Comment: This question and answers led me to my solution, thanks. Just wondering how you solved the problem you had highlighted in the fourth comment about a new country_code being added all the time. Thanks @MarkSwardstrom

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this gem for importing CSV:
https://github.com/michaelnera/active_record_importer

It's easy to use.

Comment: I'll take a look and see which one works best. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help. Below is what ended up working for me. The biggest issue i was getting was Origin and Destination. There is only one Port table, which includes a list of the Ports. Ports are used for both Origin and Destination.

```
class Rate < ApplicationRecord

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      rate = find_by_id(row["id"])
      Rate.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end

  belongs_to :origin, :class_name => 'Port'
  belongs_to :destination, :class_name => 'Port'
  belongs_to :carrier
  belongs_to :shipment_category
  belongs_to :unit_of_measure
  has_many :additional_items

# associatiing Origin and Destination Port Code
def origin_port_code
  origin.try(:port_code)
end

def origin_port_code=(port_code)
  self.origin = Port.where(:port_code => port_code).first
end

def destination_port_code
  destination.try(:port_code)
end

def destination_port_code=(port_code)
  self.destination = Port.where(:port_code => port_code).first
end

# associating carrier name
  def carrier_name
    carrier_name.try(:name)
    #code
  end
  def carrier_name=(name)
    self.carrier = Carrier.where(:name => name).first
    #code
  end


# associating Shipment Category Name
  def shipment_category_name
    shipment_category.try(:name)
  end

  def shipment_category_name=(name)
    self.shipment_category = ShipmentCategory.where(:name => name).first
  end



  # associating unit_of_measure name
  def unit_of_measure_name
    unit_of_measure.try(:name)
    #code
  end
  def unit_of_measure_name=(name)
    self.unit_of_measure = UnitOfMeasure.where(:name => name).first
    #code
  end


end
```